# Transform x,y pixel values into lat and long

Tags: python, math, geolocation, maps, geography

I  have latitude, longitude and zoom of center of my map window. I have dimension map window. I also have pixel positions of specific events on the map (mercator projection  -openstreetmap ) in the window. Can Anyone help me how to convert these pixel positions into latitude and longitude coordinates or any other coordinate system that I will be able to visualize on different map later ?
[general case of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFmJ8.jpg)

Comment: This depends a lot on the library you are using and especially what projection the library is using. There are a million ways to display a map given the quantities you stated. Please narrow down your question to make it answerable.

Comment: Pixel data of point ( point B are in mercartor projection - downloaded from openstreetmap) I have uploaded  a picture of  general case of my problem.  I am not using any library I just have thees data. From what I understand  math behind simple cursor to latlong  should be enough. But I am somehow lost in the problem.

Comment: How did you download the map? Is it a specific tile or is it already a conglomerated excerpt? The [OSM Wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Tile_numbers_to_lon..2Flat._2) has information for the former case.

Comment: I did not downloaded it. I just downloaded the pixel positions relative to upper left corner of current map window and the center point.. I have read your suggestion and tried to use it but no luck.

Comment: Again: We need a lot more details: Where is the window coming from? How does it display the map? What do you mean by downloading a pixel position? You know what you are doing - we don't.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution using this formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator_projection )
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koi6M.png)

1. calculate the x,y position of my center point
2. trasform coordinate system of window to global
3. inverse transformation

   ```
     def LatLontoXY(lat_center,lon_center,zoom):
        C =(256/(2*pi) )* 2**zoom

        x=C*(math.radians(lon_center)+pi)
        y=C*(pi-math.log( math.tan(  (pi/4) + math.radians(lat_center)/2    )  ))

        return x,y

    def xy2LatLon(lat_center,lon_center,zoom,width_internal,height_internal,pxX_internal,pxY_internal):

        xcenter,ycenter=LatLontoXY(lat_center,lon_center,zoom)

        xPoint=xcenter- (width_internal/2-pxX_internal)
        ypoint=ycenter -(height_internal/2-pxY_internal)


        C = (256 / (2 * pi)) * 2 ** zoom
        M = (xPoint/C)-pi
        N =-(ypoint/C) + pi

        lon_Point =math.degrees(M)
        lat_Point =math.degrees( (math.atan( math.e**N)-(pi/4))*2 )

        return lat_Point,lon_Point
   ```